# Redirect if the page is not found via HTAccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to be able to redirect versions of a product that returns a 404 error in a query string url back to the main product URL for example

```
www.domain.com/product.html?id=234 - 200 ok

www.domain.com/product.html?id=236 - 404 error
```

Leave /product.html?id=234 as it is due to it returning a 200 status

Redirect /product.html?id=236 to /product.html as it returns a 404 status

Is this possible via the .htaccess??

Comment: How would .htaccess know if `id=236` causes  `404 error`?

Comment: There is a statement that you can put in the htaccess to check if not found and send user to specified 404 page I was unsure if this could be used as a query string

Answer (score 0):

> There is a statement that you can put in the htaccess to check if not found and send user to specified 404 page I was unsure if this could be used as a query string

Sure, but that only checks if `product.html` exists. It doesn't actually run any scripts to verify that `id=236` is valid or not. You need to make the change in your script, the place where it validates the `id` parameter. If it finds that the ID is a 404, then it needs to do the redirect from there.

The htaccess file can't help you here.

Comment: You'd have to figure out in your PHP code that you have a 404 status (presumably already done), and redirect via a `header("Location:...` or similar to your desired catch-all target, rather than falling over dead with a 404.